# Spring MVC framework very basic Dispatcher question

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I'm looking at Spring FrameWork 3.0 I see the following code example:

```
@RequestMapping("/index.dlp")
public ModelAndView index(){
    logger.info("Return View");
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```

This option doesn't work for me. Only when I change the code the following way:

```
@RequestMapping("/index.dlp")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        logger.info("Return View");
        return new ModelAndView("index.jsp");
    }
```

It works fine. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

View names are resolved into the actual views by `ViewResolver`s.

To refer JSP pages by short names, you need to supply `InternalResourceViewResolver` with `prefix` and `suffix`. The following configuration maps `index` to `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**See also:**

- [15.5 Resolving views](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver)

Comment: This is what I like: both question and answer are clear, understandable and correct. Hence +1 to both

Comment: Thank you. Perfect and what If I would like to create two different beans one for /WEB-INF/jsp/ and second for /WEB-INF/forms/ or /WEB-INF/forms/jsp/? Thank you. Danny.

Comment: @danny: Then you can use `/WEB-INF/` as a prefix and `jsp/index` and `forms/index` as view names.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not get you. what "view name" actually refers to? Could you give small example? thank you.

Comment: OfCouse :)  return "/forms/loginform"; sorry for stupid question. works perfectly.